# open html page in left side div

Tags: html, hyperlink

I am new to bootstrap css.

I have a left div that contains my menu list and I want to open the page in right side div when user clicks on that link. Many links I came across use frames which I am not using/ intend using.

This is my code:

I have this in my left panel
`<li><a href="abc.html" target="targetPanel">Click me</a></li>`

and I have this `<div id="targetPanel" class="col-md-9"></div>`

the code of course does not work as expected and opens my page into a new tab. Is there any way that I can open it in right side div?

NOTE: I am not using any frameworks or any other support like PHP, JSP etc. I am supposed to work with pure HTML only.

Comment: Since you can't use PHP, [iframes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) would be the only way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to do this using pure HTML only is an iframe:

```
<div  class="col-md-9"><iframe src="about:blank" name="targetPanel"  style="width:100%;height:500px;"></iframe></div>
```

The `target` attribute of the link will refer to the name of the iframe so the link should open inside that iframe.  Note: I used a fixed height of 500px for the iframe, you'll need to adjust the height to your needs.  You can also find javascript snippets that can resize the iframe according to it's contents (although with some limitations).

AJAX is another option, that would involve setting a click handler on the link which cancels the default behaviour and instead, does an asynchronous GET request on the url, then parses the returned data and injects it into the div.  There are many caveats to that method though, you'll have to strip out everything except the contents of the `<body>` tag before you inject it and the injected "document" will inherit/be affected by any styles present on your page.